# Automating IE using VBA on a Mac, connecting to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, internet-explorer, macos, vba, ado

I am currently automating Internet Explorer with VBA, running through screens on our company intranet and inputting the data to an Access database.  MS Access 2007, IE7, Windows XP SP3.

I will be migrating these data tables shortly to a SQL Server database on a server running Windows Server.  I will use the same Access VBA code, with only slight modifications.

Company executives have asked if it is possible to run any of this on a Mac.  Google tells me:

1. that Office 2011 for Mac does include VBA;

   that a Mac can have IE5 (IE5 is fine with me);

   that Office 2011 for Mac does not include MS Access.

So my questions are, then:

1. Is it possible to automate IE5 using MS Office 2011 on a Mac?

   Since I cannot use MS Access on a Mac, is it possible *on a Mac* to connect VBA directly to the SQL database on the server, say using ADO?

The question applies to any Mac; we haven't bought ours yet.  Whether we are able to finance it depends on the answer to this question! :)

Thank you for your time!  (This is my first post to stackoverflow.)

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience in the field, but making this work on OS X sounds like a suicide mission.

However, you can [run Windows on newer Macs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_Camp_%28software%29) (or Virtualize it inside OS X using [Parallels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallels_Desktop)), so this should be possible to do *some* way on Mac hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Working with IE5 and using Excel as the front-end to a database probably won't be fun, but here's what I found:

You can connect to SQL Server with Excel and VBA, and that *probably* will work on a Mac (though I don't know for sure).  However you won't have a front-end database, just the back-end in SQL Server, so you won't be able to create nice reports except in VBA Code (I have produced XHTML reports with VBA and they can be quite nice).
See this article on [automating IE5 in Visual Basic](http://www.zanshu.com/ebook/165_07ie5/HTML/ch06e.htm) (before .NET, not a far cry from VBA)
Also, take a look at this article on [connecting to SQL Server with Excel and VBA Using ADO](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/isvvba/thread/f599f280-b786-43f4-9357-77f19a107c3f/).